# Is it possible to clone a random content in a div to another page?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="dynamicInput">

 </div>
```

At run time I am generating form in this `div`. Once a button is pressed I want all the included content to be transfered to another HTML page `div` tag.
Is it possible?

Comment: yes, this is possible

Comment: can you please tell me in java . as my code is in java . or just by using html or javascript

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this with html and javascript :

```
<div id="staticinput">bla bla</div>
<div id="dynamicInput">here your ramdom content</div> 

<form action="./your_page_result" method="post">
  <input name="content" id="content" type="hidden"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('content').value=document.getElementById('dynamicInput').innerHTML">
</form>
```

### so in this case :

the form will send the content to another page that you specify in action

Comment: Actually i am adding dynamic elements like radio buttons, textbox etc in my div id through .js page, and on submit or click to another page i want to display the same dynamic added elements to other page, but not really getting how to? please help.. thankyou

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hn0f5ukp/

Comment: My code snipet ... Form is randomly generating in dynamicInput div element as per selection and after that I want that div dynamicInput to be displayed in another page